# looping through array and appending to string in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, nsstring, append

I really need to loop through an array, then if array[iterator] != 0 {

I need to append the array[iterator] value, a Long to a nsstring

I am aware of

```
 int G = 23456;

 NSString *B = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lolol %d", G];
```

but I dont know how to *append* to a string.

Thank You!

Comment: Please, please, read the docs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As NSGod notes, there are a couple methods on `NSString` that can concatenate and return strings. However, if you're planning on appending many times, you probably want to use [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is optimized for such cases.

For example (based on the problem you're trying to solve):

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];

for (int iterator = 0; iterator < count; iterator++) {
    if (array[iterator] != 0) {
        [str appendFormat:@" %li", array[iterator]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is one possibility:

```
NSString *existingString = @"existingString";

long G = 23456;

existingString = [existingString
       stringByAppendingFormat:@"lolol %d", G];
```